# Type Generics messing with explicit types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a HOC that gives me a type error:

> Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

First I assign my HOC:

```
const ComponentPage = renderPage(Component);
```

Then this gives me the error:

```
return <ComponentPage chaptersCompleted={chaptersCompleted} title="title" />
```

These are my type definitions:

```
export type ChapterProps<T> = {
    [key: string]: T
}

export type PageProps = {
    chaptersCompleted: number[]
    animation?: 'fade' | 'slide' | 'instant'
}
```

And my higher-order-component:

```
export function renderPage<T>(Component: React.FC<ChapterProps<T>>) {
    
    return (props: PageProps & ChapterProps<T>) => {...}
}
```

In my component, I pass the type "string" to the generic type:

```
export function Component({title}: ChapterProps<string>) { ... }
```

If I write `ChapterProps<any>`, it works.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Why are the PageProps apparently assigned to the generic type and how can I prevent this?

###### Demo

[Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-cckdhd?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

#### Edit:

I could assign a prop with a key from the PageProps to the generic type and assign it a value with a different type than the one defined in PageProps. When I combine both types – the PageProps and the ChapterProps with the generic type, that causes the conflict. So I need to find a way to first exclude the PageProps from the ChapterPros and them combine both types what I'm currently failing at.

Comment: Do you mind reproducing in jsfiddle so its easier for us to assist you.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-cckdhd?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I looked through the code for a bit but couldnt immediately tell why **tsc** compiler is whinging. However i did provide a solution based on the error by creating a union type between Component's props and PageProps. Component props will look like this `export function Component({ title }: ChapterProps<string | PageProps[keyof PageProps]>) {`. 

Why do you need a `HOC` with functional components? 
Will your `HOC` be the root level component?

Comment: Thank you. Seems a little laborious to always pass the Page props where they should not be needed, though. And it spoils my typing a bit as this is what it makes of it: `ChapterProps<string | number[] | undefined>`. Yes, the HOC is my root component. Makes it more concise compared to nesting components.

Comment: Yeah it seems long having to provide props where they are not needed. Furthermore it brings about unnecessary complexity. Will each Page (`Component`) have its own custom `props`?.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the child component is as generic as possible. The HOC should have the same props. I wonder why Typescript is trying to inject the types from PageProps into the type arguments of ChapterProps rather than combining both types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257104/discussion-between-mirja-t-and-remedy-man).

Answer (score 0):

For typing HOC try to use React.ComponentType

```
export function renderPage<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) { }
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, that leads to the same result. Why should React.ComponentType be preferred over React.FC for a component passed to a HOC as argument?